# Autowired Bean not found, SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning SpringBoot and I built a simple "sample" app but I'm having trouble injecting the different components together.

I get `Field b in ca.company.hello.A required a bean of type 'ca.company.hello.B' that could not be found. The injection point has the following annotations:
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

}
```

Here is how I use the class `B`:

```
@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Value("Covid 19")
    private String calamity;

    public void speak() {
        b.writeToScreen(this.calamity);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me please, how do I inject class `B` correctly into the field `b` in class `A` above?

P.S.

Here is the package structure of my project:

[image]

And here is my main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Helloer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // EDIT:  I'm now using ctx to create the A object as per suggestions below. Same error though
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(A.class, args);
        A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
        a.speak();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: add package structure in you project

Comment: `Helloer` class should be in root package. Move it to `ca.company`.

Comment: Did it. Didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot Must find the Beans (`A` and `B`) during the scanning. It has some component scanning rules that should be obeyed (see the explanation in "item 2" below) + the class marked with `SpringBootApplication` is wrong, these two issues cause the problem:

Solution:

1. Fix the `Helloer` class:

Note, that `Helloer` is passed to `SpringApplication.run`.

Another issue is that `A` should be managed By Spring itself, otherwise, if you do a `new A()` - the autowiring magic won't happen. In general, everything that has autowiring in one way or another must be managed by spring dependency injection container (read, under the responsibility of spring boot)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Helloer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Helloer.class, args);
        A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);
        a.speak();
    }
}
```

2. Move the config class so that its package will be the same or "inner" package related to the "Helloer". Spring boot scans everything in the package of `SpringBootApplication` and underneath by default during its startup. Only the classes under these packages can be processed by spring:

```
package ca.company.hello; // note the package - it can also be something "inside" this package, like ca.company.hello.config; otherwise spring won't find it and class B won't be "visible" for spring.


@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

}
```

If you already have config for class B, why not also manage class A in the `@Configuration` (well, this one is optional, it will work even without this change):

```
package ca.company.hello; // note the package - it can also be something "inside" this package, like ca.company.hello.config;


@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public A a() {
      return new A();
    }
    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

}
```

With this change, you don't have to put `@Component` on A - these are kind of two styles of declaring beans, spring boot will work with both.  I haven't seen the definition of the class `B` in the question, but if you manage it through the `@Configuration` then you shouldn't put a `@Component` on the class B itself

Comment: Hi. Thank you kindly. I implemented the first point (I don't use `new` anymore but instead use `A a = ctx.getBean(A.class);)` and second points above. Same problem persists though. I tried moving the config to the same package as the main, but still same error persists.

Comment: Note the parameters to the run method of springapplication. It should be Helloer.class

Answer (score 3):

You defined A to be a component. So instance of A will be created by Spring. then you say new A(). 
This creates a new instance of A for which it looks for B and doesn't find.

Anywhere in your code when you use "new" keyword, it is just another instance you are creating which Spring is not aware of, hence your error.

So you need to autowire A into the Main class and call the method a.speak.

Plus, your bootstrap class is wrong, you are bootstraping class A, but the run method expects a class which is annotated with SpringBootConfiguration. That is how SpringBoot starts the application.

So your code should be :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Helloer {
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Hellor.class, args);
        a.speak();
    }
}
```

If you do not want to autowire A, second thing you can do is, SpringApplication.run() method returns ApplicationContext. Hold it in a variable and then say context.getBean("a", A.class) -> this returns the instance of A from the Spring Context. Then you can call the a.speak()

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class Helloer {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Hellor.class, args);
            A a = ctx.getBean("a", A.class);
            a.speak();
        }
    }
```